# ng-show not working with <select>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to hide or display a `<select>` tag based on the array reference being `[]` or not. The `<select>` tag is backed by the same array.

```
<select ng-show="model.people" ng-model="model.selectedPerson" ng-options="person.name for person in model.people"></select>
```

However its not working. `model.people` is initially `[]`.

When the first element is added, using `model.addPerson()`, I was hoping `model.people` to be truthy and hence set ng-show to truthy value and ultimately have the `<select>` tag displayed.

javascript code:

```
angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('FormController', function($scope) {
            var model={};
            model.person=function(person){
                return{
                        name:person.name,
                        age:person.age
                        };
            };
            model.people=[];
            model.addPerson=function(person){
                model.people.push(new model.person(person));
                if(model.people){
                    console.log(true);
                }else{
                    console.log(false);
                }
            };
            model.selectedPerson=model.people[0];
            $scope.model=model;
        });
```

HTML code:

```
<form name="form" ng-controller="FormController" ng-submit="model.addPerson(model.anyPerson)" novalidate>
    <input type="text" ng-model="model.anyPerson.name" ng-required="true" placeholder="Name"/><br/>
    <input type="number" name="age" ng-model="model.anyPerson.age" min="15" max="100" ng-required="true" placeholder="Age"/><br/>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Add Person</button><br/>
    <select ng-show="model.people" ng-model="model.selectedPerson" ng-options="person.name for person in model.people"></select><br/>
    <span ng-show="model.selectedPerson" ng-bind-template="Name: {{model.selectedPerson.name}}, Age: {{model.selectedPerson.age}}"></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An empty array (once assigned) becomes an object.  It seems that this object is *always* truthy (empty or not).

```
var empty = [];
if (empty) { 1; } else { 2; }
```

The above code, in my testing always returns `1`.

Therefore, I suggest that you use `length > 0` in the `ng-show` instead:

```
<select ng-show="model.people.length > 0" ng-model="model.selectedPerson" ng-options="person.name for person in model.people"></select>
```